# Columns & FilteredTree in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jface, rcp, treeviewer

I'm trying to create a `FilteredTree` with several columns with no luck. If I use a `TreeViewer` the columns work fine but when I switch to using a `FilteredTree` I can only get it to work if I remove the columns, so I'm wondering if there is a way to use `FilteredTree` with columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use a FilteredTree with a column viewer. For example (and this also demonstrates preserving the use of a TreeColumnLayout using a FilteredTree):

```
final TreeColumnLayout tl = new TreeColumnLayout();

PatternFilter patternFilter = new PatternFilter();
patternFilter.setIncludeLeadingWildcard(true);
FilteredTree ft = new FilteredTree(treeViewerComposite, SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | toolkit.getBorderStyle() | Window.getDefaultOrientation(), patternFilter, true) {            
   @Override
   protected Control createTreeControl(Composite parent, int style) {
       Control c = super.createTreeControl(parent, style);
       c.setLayoutData(null);
       c.getParent().setLayout(tl);
       return c;
   }        
};

viewer = ft.getViewer();
viewer.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
```

Now you can just create TreeColumn's the usual way and your columns will appear.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code will result in an assertion failure. The layout setup code is not correct in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way as with a [normal Tree](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTTreeWithMulticolumns.htm). Here is a full setup.

```
PatternFilter patternFilter = new PatternFilter();
patternFilter.setIncludeLeadingWildcard(true);
filteredTree = new FilteredTree(getContainer(), SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL, patternFilter, true);

TreeViewer viewer = filteredTree.getViewer();
tree = viewer.getTree();
tree.setHeaderVisible(true);

TreeColumn modelColumn = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
modelColumn.setText("Model");
modelColumn.setWidth(400);

TreeViewerColumn treeViewerModelColumn = new TreeViewerColumn(viewer, modelColumn);
treeViewerModelColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, and the solution it is outlined here: 
http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/10/26/filtering-tables-in-swtjface/

[image: image from EclipseSource blog]

The point is the default `PatternFilter` needs tree leaves to be instance of `ILabelProvider`. In a column-based treeviewer there is no single text representation for the tree leaf.

So, if you are using `TreeViewerColumns` as tree columns, the `PatternFilter` will use the `ColumnLabelProvider` for each column. In this case you'll fix by subclassing the `PatternFilter` and overriding it with your own `isLeafMatch(..)`

Otherwise, when using `TreeColumns` to define columns, the `TreeViewer` will need to have a `ITableLabelProvider`. Beyond this, you'll subclass the `PatternFilter` and, again, override the method `isLeafMatch(..)`